# Download.file() incongruent with Manual Download

Tags: r, curl, grib

I am working with data from: [Environment Canada](http://dd.weather.gc.ca/model_gem_global/25km/grib2/lat_lon/00/000/)

I am using `download.file()` to acquire this data. When I use:

```
download.file(url="http://dd.weather.gc.ca/model_gem_global/25km/grib2/lat_lon/00/000/CMC_glb_VGRD_ISBL_1000_latlon.24x.24_2015091100_P000.grib2",destfile = "Local_Grib.grib2")
GribInfo(grib.file = "Local_File.grib2",file.type = "grib2")
```

It yields:

```
$inventory
[1] ""                                                                "*** FATAL ERROR: rd_grib2_msg, missing end section ('7777') ***"
[3] ""                                                               
attr(,"status")
[1] 8

$grid
[1] ""                                                                "*** FATAL ERROR: rd_grib2_msg, missing end section ('7777') ***"
[3] ""                                                               
attr(,"status")
[1] 8

Warning messages:
1: running command 'wgrib2 Local_File.grib2 -inv -' had status 8 
2: running command 'wgrib2 Local_File.grib2 -grid' had status 8
```

Whilst a manual download followed by:

```
GribInfo(grib.file = "CMC_glb_TMP_ISBL_985_latlon.24x.24_2015091100_P000.grib2",file.type = "grib2")
```

Yields:

```
$inventory
[1] "1:0:d=2015091100:TMP:985 mb:anl:"

$grid
[1] "1:0:grid_template=0:winds(N/S):"                                        "\tlat-lon grid:(1500 x 751) units 1e-06 input WE:SN output WE:SN res 48"
[3] "\tlat -90.000000 to 90.000000 by 0.240000"                               "\tlon 180.000000 to 179.760000 by 0.240000 #points=1126500"
```

I have attempted using the Curl and Wget methods within `download.file()` however they fail giving a non exit error. I am able to obtain these files using a wget batch file however, I would prefer my entire system be run within R for consistency and ease of use.

Comment: @MartinMorgan, Did the trick, thank you very much, should have checked that first! I when through all the methods but not the modes! Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Martin Morgan. Downloading as a binary will circumvent this issue. Thanks again Martin.

```
download.file(url="http://dd.weather.gc.ca/model_gem_global/25km/grib2/lat_lon/00/000/CMC_glb_VGRD_ISBL_1000_latlon.24x.24_2015091100_P000.grib2",destfile = "Local_Grib.grib2", mode="wb")
GribInfo(grib.file = "Local_File.grib2",file.type = "grib2")
```